# How to build with Ruby in Visual Studio and CMake

Tags: ruby, visual-studio, cmake

I need to use Visual Studio's Ruby C API for a C++ project, and there are not many examples of how to include Ruby and build a solution.

I used CMake to create the Visual Studio 2013 solution and included some libraries, among them Ruby with FindRuby.cmake.

Where I'm stuck is, when trying to build the solution I get errors that Ruby can't find headers like "strings.h" among others, I know that these are possibly not from Ruby, but I can't find examples of how to include them with CMake and that Ruby can use them.

And I also feel that even if I manage to include those headers, I will get other types of errors because I am doing something wrong.

And if there is another way to use Ruby without CMake I would like to know.

I use Visual Studio 2013 although I could use 2017, and I use CMake-Gui 3.17.1

Here is the part of CMakeLists where I include Ruby:

```
find_package(Ruby REQUIRED )

if (RUBY_INCLUDE_PATH)
    set(RUBY_FOUND "TRUE")
else()
    set(RUBY_FOUND "FALSE")
endif (RUBY_INCLUDE_PATH)

include_directories(${RUBY_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

The first errors I get in Visual Studio when building the solution are:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'strings.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdalign.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What version of CMake are you using? Are you using the `FindRuby.cmake` module provided by CMake? The latest CMake version warns against using `RUBY_INCLUDE_PATH`, and `RUBY_FOUND` should be set for you...see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindRuby.html). Also, can you provide the exact error messages you are encountering when building in Visual Studio. A description of the error is not very helpful.

Comment: @squareskittles I use CMake-Gui 3.17.1, and the module of FindRuby provided by CMake, I tried using RUBY_INCLUDE_DIRS instead of RUBY_INCLUDE_PATH but it does the same, I edited the post with the error messages.

Comment: Read CRuby's `win32\README.win32`. It's the only official way to build it with Visual C++. After that you should be able to use CMake and FindRuby.

Comment: @cremno I'm not sure if you understand my question, I have Ruby and CMake finds it, I don't need to build Ruby from the source, what I want is to use it in a Visual Studio project. Ruby has a C Api and I need to use it from C++.

Comment: How did you build CRuby? I'm asking because VC++ doesn't have those headers and CRuby should be aware of that, so my best guess was you didn't build CRuby according to the readme.

Comment: Another possibility is FindRuby found the wrong Ruby. E.g. the RubyInstaller one and not the one you've build with VC++.

Comment: Welcome! I'd highly recommend reading "[ask]" and its linked pages, "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"
and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". They'll help you understand how to work with a community like SO.

Comment: Ruby can't find those headers, but I doubt it has to do with that is bad built, also I don't build CRuby, I install Ruby with RubyInstaller. FindRuby does find Ruby, but in Visual Studio it gives me errors that Ruby can't find some headers. (strings.h, stdalign.h, unistd.h, etc)